# PHP causes server shutdown

Tags: php, server, crash, garbage-collection, resource-cleanup

I have a centos server with 4Gb RAM.
I'm doing a PHP console batch process that may take some hours... however it doesn't finish as the server shutdown after 1 or 2 hours from lauching the process...
Here are the logs:

```
    Dec 28 04:39:01 www systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
    Dec 28 04:39:02 www systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped target Mail Transport Agent.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 0...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping Session 12236053 of user root.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Stopped target Default.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Stopped target Basic System.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Stopped target Sockets.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Reached target Shutdown.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Starting Exit the Session...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Stopped target Timers.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Stopped target Paths.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping Session 12226070 of user root.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped Run certbot twice daily.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt download activities.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped Clean PHP session files every 30 mins.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping Console Getty...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty2...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: modules.dep creation....
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping Unattended Upgrades Shutdown...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Start/stop sysstat's sadc...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping Runit service supervision...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping D-Bus System Message Bus...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[24724]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 11820 (kill).
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts or stops the xinetd daemon....
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd FTP server...
    Dec 28 04:40:04 www rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.20.0" x-pid="370" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

It starts the clean php session files then suddently stops all services and shuts down!

My code seems ok....do I need to force cleaning the variables on code?

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Might this be better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: batch process could be causing dos?

Comment: @peter-czask Have you get the solution for that problem?